# ProjMaker.html_Proj_Maker() - missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, function, class, module, self

I need to use my class's attributes in my define.

ProjMaker.py:

```
import os
class ProjMaker():
    ProjLoc = os.getcwd()
    def html_Proj_Maker(self):
        Project_location = self.ProjLoc
        return (Project_location)
```

main.py

```
from assets.ProjMaker import ProjMaker as Pom
print(Pom.html_Proj_Maker())
```

I don't know how to use `self`.

Please help me out!